# Migrate MySQL to MSSQL with views

Tags: sql-server, mysql, migration

I have one MySQL database and I want to migrate it with data to MSSQL. I have tried a few tools including MS SQL server Import and Export wizard, DataLoader, ESF Database migration toolkit, mysqldump with --compatible=mssql.

All of these tools are working, but it is migrating views as tables.

Do you have any experience with the tool that can migrate views as well?

Comment: Have you tried using SQL Server Migration Assistant (https://datamigration.microsoft.com/scenario/mysql-to-sqlserver?step=1&tabnav=true)

Answer (score 1):

Rather unfortunately ... https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/20-tips-on-converting-mysql-views-to-ms-sql

> Although there are many free tools and solutions to migrate MySQL data to MS SQL server, none of them is able to convert views. That's why everybody who wants to migrate complete database have to convert views manually ...

After that they give 20 tips on how to convert the view-declaration so that mssql understands it. Unfortunately this means you have to work view by view .. by hand